# Mesh has overlapping faces/triangles

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, 3d, rendering

[image: Chunk Face Render Bug]

To put some content, I've developed a chunk-generation-system that can randomly generate blocks into 1 mesh for optimization. (Similar to Minecraft.) All of the vertices, triangles, UV's and etc. are all made from scratch. Depending on which way you look, faces clip through one another as shown in the GIF. What would be the go-to possible issue that is occurring here? Basic idea of how the generation works:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {     //For each block in chunk being loaded on x axis,
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {     //For each block in chunk being loaded on y axis,
            for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {     //For each block in chunk being loaded on z axis,

                if (exists[x, y, z] == true) {

                    Vector2[] normalUVs = {
                        new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(.1f, 0), new Vector2(.1f, .1f), new Vector2(0, .1f)
                    };

                    normalUVs[0] = new Vector2(normalUVs[0].x + (texPosX[x, y, z] ), normalUVs[0].y + (texPosY[x, y, z] ));
                    normalUVs[1] = new Vector2(normalUVs[1].x + (texPosX[x, y, z] ), normalUVs[1].y + (texPosY[x, y, z] ));
                    normalUVs[2] = new Vector2(normalUVs[2].x + (texPosX[x, y, z] ), normalUVs[2].y + (texPosY[x, y, z] ));
                    normalUVs[3] = new Vector2(normalUVs[3].x + (texPosX[x, y, z] ), normalUVs[3].y + (texPosY[x, y, z] ));


                    Vector2[] flippedUVs = {
                        new Vector2(.1f, .1f), new Vector2(0, .1f), new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(.1f, 0)
                    };

                    flippedUVs[0] = new Vector2(flippedUVs[0].x + (texPosX[x, y, z] ), flippedUVs[0].y + (texPosY[x, y, z] ));
                    flippedUVs[1] = new Vector2(flippedUVs[1].x + (texPosX[x, y, z] ), flippedUVs[1].y + (texPosY[x, y, z] ));
                    flippedUVs[2] = new Vector2(flippedUVs[2].x + (texPosX[x, y, z] ), flippedUVs[2].y + (texPosY[x, y, z] ));
                    flippedUVs[3] = new Vector2(flippedUVs[3].x + (texPosX[x, y, z] ), flippedUVs[3].y + (texPosY[x, y, z] ));

                    Vector2[] heightUVs = {
                        new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(0, .1f), new Vector2(.1f, .1f), new Vector2(.1f, 0)
                    };

                    heightUVs[0] = new Vector2(heightUVs[0].x + (texPosX[x, y, z] ), heightUVs[0].y + (texPosY[x, y, z] ));
                    heightUVs[1] = new Vector2(heightUVs[1].x + (texPosX[x, y, z] ), heightUVs[1].y + (texPosY[x, y, z] ));
                    heightUVs[2] = new Vector2(heightUVs[2].x + (texPosX[x, y, z] ), heightUVs[2].y + (texPosY[x, y, z] ));
                    heightUVs[3] = new Vector2(heightUVs[3].x + (texPosX[x, y, z] ), heightUVs[3].y + (texPosY[x, y, z] ));

                    List<Vector3> visibleVerts = new List<Vector3>();     //Used as a temp array
                    List<int> visibleTris = new List<int>();     //Used as a temp array
                    List<Vector2> visibleUVs = new List<Vector2>();     //Used as a temp array
```

Example of how front face is added to array of vertices, UV's, and triangles:

```
if ((z == 0 && exists[x, y, z] == true) || (z > 0 && exists[x, y, z - 1] == false)) {     //If there's not a block in front of this one or if it's on the edge of the chunk,

                        faces = new Vector3[] {
                        new Vector3 (0 + x, 0 + y, 0 + z),   
                        new Vector3 (0 + x, 1 + y, 0 + z),      
                        new Vector3 (1 + x, 1 + y, 0 + z),    
                        new Vector3 (1 + x, 0 + y, 0 + z)    
                        };

                        tris = new int[] {
                            0 + (faceCount * 4),     //0
                            1 + (faceCount * 4),     //1
                            2 + (faceCount * 4),     //2
                            0 + (faceCount * 4),     //0
                            2 + (faceCount * 4),     //2
                            3 + (faceCount * 4)     //3
                        };

                        visibleVerts.AddRange(faces);
                        visibleTris.AddRange(tris);
                        visibleUVs.AddRange(normalUVs);
                        faceCount++;
                    }
```

[UPDATE] The issue seems to occur here. If I decrement these loops of how the vertices generate, the rendering issue occurs on the opposite side of the mesh.
[image: Issue lies here]

Comment: I would try to narrow down the problem, seems that it is a rendering problem, not related to the mesh generation or your elements position. In that case all the posted code would not be relevant. I would check if the problem reproduces for a material that is rendering according to the cemera's z for example the unity's default material with different colours so that you can differenciate the cubes. If the problem does not occur in this case, you would need to check your material/shader and its behaviour regarding blending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ardor stated,

> Switching the render mode of your project would probably also help, but would nit really fix the problem of your meshes origins, just fix the effect.

My rendering mode was **TRANSPARENT**. I then switched the materials to have the rendering mode **OPAQUE**. This fixed the issue. Though, if I ever want to have transparent blocks/meshes, this issue will be raised again.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure your problem is the sorting of objects in the render pipeline. It looks like your meshes all have the same origin, which is used by the pipeline to sort them. You might be better off using a mesh where the origin is in the center of your cube, then moving the GameObject it attached to to the according world position. Then the sorting should work properly again.

Note: this only happens in one of the two render pipelines (forward/deferred) as far as I know and I'm quite sure it's in the forward one, but not 100%. So switching the render mode of your project would probably also help, but would nit really fix the problem of your meshes origins, just fix the effect.

Comment: It's all the same mesh though! As you said though, I did discover that it seems to be occurring from the x,y,z for-loops of how the vertices generate. If I flip the for-loops to decrement, the render issue occurs on the opposite side of the mesh. I updated the post. Is there anyway I can almost make it 'recalculate' in anyway? Thanks.

Comment: Based on your observation I'd assume the triangles in the mesh are not sorted at all, but just rendered in the order you create them. If this is the case, you can just re-calculate it whenever the camera moves (which sounds awefully inperformant). You could also put every cube into a sub-mesh, that should solve your sorting problem, too. (but I'm not sure if there is a limit on the number of submeshes in one mesh)
Some of the solutions on this answer might help you, too: https://answers.unity.com/questions/609021/how-to-fix-transparent-rendering-problem.html